# Can anyone help me figuring out why this executes multiple times when checking for the voucherType?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, prisma, vercel

I am trying to create a user when i receive the charge.succeeded webhook from stripe but the code runs twice (the email is sent twice the user cannot be created twice because paymentId is unique in my database so i get the error, so far so good). The problem seems strange to me because before i didn't check the type of the voucher in a version before `const activeVoucher = await prisma.voucher.findFirst({ where: { active: true, voucherType: getCorrectVoucher(data.data.object.amount)}});` and everything worked perfectly fine. but now since i added this feature it seems to be running in a loop and i can't figure out why. does anyone have an idea why this could be ?

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

  export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {

    const getCorrectVoucher = (data: number): string => {
        switch (data) {
            case 12000:
                return '101';
            case 23000:
                return '102';
            case 20000:
                return '201';
            case 40000:
                return '202';
            default:
                return 'price not found';
        }
    }

    const data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);

    const host = process.env.EMAIL_SERVER;
    const user = process.env.EMAIL_USER;
    const password = process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORT;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: host,
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: user,
            pass: password
        }
    });

    switch (data.type) {
        case 'payment_intent.created':
            return NextResponse.json({messsage: 'payment intent created'}, {status: 200})

        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            return NextResponse.json({messsage: 'checkout completed'}, {status: 200})

        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            return NextResponse.json({message: 'payment intent succeeded'}, {status: 200})

        case 'charge.succeeded':
            const prisma = new PrismaClient();
            const customerMail = data.data.object.billing_details.email;
            const activeVoucher = await prisma.voucher.findFirst({ where: { active: true, voucherType: getCorrectVoucher(data.data.object.amount)}});
            const subject = 'Gutschein';
          
            if (activeVoucher?.id) {
                await prisma.voucher.update({
                    where: { id: activeVoucher.id },
                    data: { active: false }
                });
          
                const message = `Vielen Dank für deine Bestellung, anbei der Gutscheincode ${activeVoucher.voucherCode}`;

                await prisma.user.create({
                    data: {
                        email: customerMail,
                        voucher: activeVoucher.voucherCode,
                        voucherType: getCorrectVoucher(data.data.object.amount),
                        paymentId: data.id,
                        paymentStatus: 'payed'
                    }
                });
          
                try {
                    await transporter.sendMail({
                        from: user,
                        to: customerMail,
                        subject,
                        text: `Gutscheinbestellung\nEmail: ${customerMail}\nNachricht: ${message}`
                    });
          
                    console.log(activeVoucher.id);
                    console.log(activeVoucher.voucherCode);
                    console.log(activeVoucher.active);
                    
                    await prisma.$disconnect();
                    
                    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'success' }, { status: 200 });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    await prisma.$disconnect();
                    return NextResponse.json({ message: `email and database update failed: ${error}` }, { status: 500 });
                }
            } else {
                console.log(activeVoucher?.voucherCode);
                throw new Error('No active voucher found.');
            }
        default:
            return NextResponse.json({message: 'webhook success'}, {status: 200})  
        }           
}
```

Comment: What does Postgres have to do with the problem? If "nothing", please remove the Postgres tag from the question.

Comment: in your try/catch, does it hit the catch at some point after it sends the message and before it returns 200? If it hits the catch and returns 500, stripe will retry the webhook

Comment: Nodemailer is a yellow flag here. Are you sure it is executing properly when deployed, without attempting to do async work?
If you have a scenario where `nodemailer` is putting things in the event loop that will "freeze" and not be executed after a reply has been sent, then they could be executed after a new request comes in, and you may get the "duplicate code running" behavior. I would check for timestamps on your logs + Stripe to better debug this issue. Prefer using mail clients as a service that offer HTTP APIs